# Zooming on Chrome causes CSS position changes

Tags: html, css

I have table layout as fixed

```css
table {
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  table-layout: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Part No</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th style="text-align:center; width:100%; position:relative;z-index:5;">Part Status</th>
    <th>Zone</th>
    <th>Min Qty</th>
    <th>Max Qty</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Proposed Cost</th>
    <th>Varience (%)</th>
    <th style="text-align:center; width:100%;">Status</th>
    <th>Pending Removal</th>
    <th>Approvl Status</th>
    <th>Locked</th>
    <th>EffectiveDate</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The part status and status columns there TD changing its position when i zoom it to -25%.

[image]

In image you can find partstatus(6th column) its td position is changed.
Can anybody help me out how can i solve this.

Comment: Yeah, welcome to responsive web design...

Comment: Look into flexbox. PS - That's an awfully lot of headers.

Comment: What is this flexbox all about.what are changes need to make to get it done @Highdef

Comment: i had a look.but how can i apply and idea anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). `display:inline-flex;` on table.

```css
table {
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display:inline-flex;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  table-layout: auto;

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Part No</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th style="text-align:center; width:100%; position:relative;z-index:5;">Part Status</th>
    <th>Zone</th>
    <th>Min Qty</th>
    <th>Max Qty</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Proposed Cost</th>
    <th>Varience (%)</th>
    <th style="text-align:center; width:100%;">Status</th>
    <th>Pending Removal</th>
    <th>Approvl Status</th>
    <th>Locked</th>
    <th>EffectiveDate</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Boom done :0->this were i need to add?is it in table or th? @Hash

Comment: add `display:inline-flex;` to table,  ignore the other bit :)

Comment: i tried it but td part comes correct but all TH part moves left and all Td part move one side.I have mentioned in images above.it shows same no reflection.Is that a backend issue